# How to wait multiple times in one function? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a code that will wait one second before switching something, wait one more second and switch again?

I tried using Thread.Sleep() and Delay() but both of them just skip to the final result

(If I have img1 and img2, it will not show img1 but instantly freeze everything and show img2 after all the delays are done)

How can I make it wait, run a line, wait again, run another line without it just freezing the app and showing the final result?

Comment: `delay()` in a coroutine should do it. Please share your code that didn't work so we can tell you how it should be changed.

Comment: You can't call `Thread.sleep()` on the main thread like that, it'll block *everything* from running (which is why it's freezing). That means you don't even get to see the first image - you update it so it'll display *img1* on the next frame draw, but then you freeze the app (so nothing's getting drawn) and after that you change the image again. When the next frame draw finally happens, it's set to *img2* so that's all you see. You can do this with coroutines, posted runnables, even a dedicated thread - but there might be something more suitable, like a TransitionDrawable or view animation